# Accidentally committing kufr

Tags: kufr

Asalam alaikum,today I was thinking about how I used to believe that homosexuality was okay, then I thought that thinking this is maybe kufr, so I said the shahadah, as I said the shahadah I thought that do I actually believe that believing homosexuality is okay is kufr and as I finished saying the shahadah i said out loud that no I don't believe that, now I'm thinking that did I say I don't believe that about the shahadah and am I a kafir? Sorry for bad English and I hope you understand what I mean to say

Answer (score 0):

Wa alikum misalam
Brother/sister
Don't worry you have already repented so it is alright do not ever despair the mercy of Allah(swt) he is the most forgiving most merciful
Don't you worry you have been forgiven
Even if you had the thoughts if no action has been done there is no sin
But Alumabarik you still asked
Have a nice day and don't worry at all